# Testing with Dagger 2 using separate component configurations in Android

Tags: java, android, integration-testing, dagger-2

The Dagger 2 [documentation suggests providing different configurations](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html) for testing and production using an `interface` for `ProductionComponent` and `TestComponent`, as follows:

```
@Component(modules = {
  OAuthModule.class, // real auth
  FooServiceModule.class, // real backend
  OtherApplicationModule.class,
  /* … */ })
interface ProductionComponent {
  Server server();
}

@Component(modules = {
  FakeAuthModule.class, // fake auth
  FakeFooServiceModule.class, // fake backend
  OtherApplicationModule.class,
  /* … */})
interface TestComponent extends ProductionComponent {
  FakeAuthManager fakeAuthManager();
  FakeFooService fakeFooService();
}
```

Let's say we have an Android activity (`MyApp`) which uses `ProductionComponent`:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private ProductionComponent component;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component = ProductionComponent.builder()
                .serverModule(new ServerModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Generally, what's the best way to use `DaggerTestComponent.builder()` rather than `ProductionComponent.builder()` in Android integration tests?

I'm unsure of how to use the fakes; Should I make a new activity in `/androidTest` which `extends MyApp`? Or should I pass in a new `DaggerTestComponent` into `MyApp` using a getter/setter when I setup my test?

Comment: Found a very helpful solution at https://blog.egorand.me/providing-test-doubles-with-dagger-1-and-dagger-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) with [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)?

You can make JUnit test codes with @Test without AndroidTest.
I think you make test dagger application with Mockito.

references here

http://alexzh.com/tutorials/android-testing-mockito-robolectric/
http://sdudzin.blogspot.kr/2011/01/easy-unit-testing-for-android.html